# How to do a Dry Run on an Assume Role call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

So I would like to check if a role is setup with a trust relationship. Is there a way from me to do an assume role dry-run to check the trust relationship without actually requesting temporary credentials? I know other aws api calls have dry run options that have similar effects, but I have not seen one for sts assume role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct -- there appears to be no `--dry-run` option for `assume-role`.

It probably wouldn't work anyway because Dry Run is used to check **whether you are allowed to make the API call itself**, not whether the API call would succeed.

For example, here I try to delete a snapshot with Dry Run:

```
$ aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id snap-23 --dry-run

An error occurred (DryRunOperation) when calling the DeleteSnapshot
operation: Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set.
```

And here it is without Dry Run:

```
$ aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id snap-23

An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the
DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot 'snap-00000023' does not exist.
```

Comment: One thing I found that was kinda helpful as well is the policy simulator http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html this allows you to see what a role with a specified policy would be allowed to do. Not exactly what I was asking about, but tangentially related.